# Trigger Executable/HTTP Request from CC.Net

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I'm in the process of moving build projects from CC.Net to Jenkins. However, I need to run a few projects from CC.Net for a while until the migration is complete. Simply put, I want the CC.Net project to do nothing but trigger a job in Jenkins, by using a HTTP request as remote trigger.

I've already set up everything in Jenkins. All I need to do is add the project to CC.Net and have this project trigger my Jenkins job.

I have been unsuccessful in triggering the Jenkins job. I've tried using a HTTP Request as well as an Executable (created a small console application which does the HTTP request). Whenever I try to force the build from my CCTray, the build server tells me "Exception Caught: Input string was not in a correct format.". This should give an idea about what I've tried:

```
<project name="Test32" queue="venus-02">
  <tasks>
    <exec>
      <executable>C:\key\TestRemoteTrigger.exe</executable>
    </exec>
  </tasks>
</project>
```

I don't need any fancy stuff. I *just* want the CC.Net project to run my executable. Or even better, to simply perform the HTTP Request. But I can't get it to work, and I've come up empty using Google - mostly because every topic I find is about something much more complex which is the opposite of what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after some stabbing at the keyboard I figured out it was not what I was, or was not, putting *inside* the  section... it was what I was missing outside it. And  was apparently not needed.

This will work:

```
<project name="Test32" queue="venus-02">
  <publishers>
    <exec>
      <executable>C:\key\TestRemoteTrigger.exe</executable>
    </exec>
  </publishers>
</project>
```